# Spring boot 2 + AWS Beanstalk setting heapsize

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jvm

I am trying to set JVM heapsize of Spring boot 2 application that is being deployed in AWS Beanstalk as war. I am using gradle 'bootWar' task to create war.

I placed .config file in /srv/main/resources/.ebextensions with content:

```
option_settings:
    aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
        Xmx: 512m
        Xms: 512m
```

But setting seems to be ignored.

I have also tried setting:

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions
```

But AWS failed to deploy with error:

```
InvalidParameterValue: Unknown template parameter: JVMOptions
```

How do I set JVM heap size properly?

Comment: did you tried from console Configuration > Software Configuration > Environment Properties?

Comment: i think .ebextensions folder  should be in your project root folder not in classpath, can you try by moving.

Comment: same issue... also tried setting the procfile. ps -aux | grep brings back 'webapp    3282  7.1 14.8 3535064 599072 ?      Sl   23:13   0:32 java -jar web-0.1.0.jar -Xms3512m -Xmx6g' , but when I run 'sudo jmap -heap 3282' the application is still using the default 25% os total memory....

Comment: i managed to do this with a Proc file, which is in the root zip and has the following content `web: java -Xmx512m -Xmx512m -jar server.jar`

Answer (score 0):

`.ebextensions` folder and `.config` should be in your project root folder not in `classpath`, can you try by moving should work.

or once your setup EB for your project, it automatically create `.ebextensions` in you project root folder if its already there then move your `.config` inside of it.

Comment: I tried having .ebextensions folder in project root but it was not packaged in war.

Comment: hmm .ebextensions should be placed in the root of WAR, you might set path from war plugin for .ebextensions, you can try placing under web-inf too..

Comment: Moving .ebextensions did not help either.